# ReentrantLock vs synchronized on CPU level?

Tags: java, concurrency

Is there a difference between 'ReentrantLock' and 'synchronized' on how it's implemented on CPU level? 
Or do they use the same 'CAS' approach?

Comment: Please correct me if i'm wrong. As for my knowledge, java threads are not visible to the CPU level. These locks are just an implementation which run on java runtime. Java runtime does the placement of instructions in order to make sure each thread is excuted. Locks are also used in JRE level therefore. In short, Java threads fall into software level threads, not to kernel level threads(as in windows).

Comment: If you take UNIX, there are no kernel level threads. UNIX treat threads and processes as the same. But in windows, they use kernel level threads. So my understanding is, kernel level threads have nothing to do with java threads.

Comment: @ImeshaSudasingha no, Java threads are native threads (on every JVM I know about)

Comment: @Imesha If Java threads were implemented purely in user level, you could never tax more than a single core. No production quality implementation has used such a construct (green threads) in far over a decade.

Comment: java threads are native/OS threads

Answer (score 15):

If we are talking about `ReentrantLock` vs `synchronized` (also known as "intrinsic lock") then it's a good idea to look at [Lock documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html):

> All Lock implementations must enforce the same memory synchronization semantics as provided by the built-in monitor lock:
>
> - A successful lock operation acts like a successful monitorEnter
>     action
> - A successful unlock operation acts like a successful    monitorExit
>     action

So in general consider that `synchronized` is just an easy-to-use and concise approach of locking. You can achieve exactly the same synchronization effects by writing code with `ReentrantLock` with a bit more code (but it offers more options and flexibility).

Some time ago `ReentrantLock` was way faster under certain conditions (high contention for example), but now `Java` uses different optimizations techniques (like lock coarsening and adaptive locking) to make performance differences in many typical scenarios barely visible to the programmer.

There was also done a great job to optimize intrinsic lock in low-contention cases (e.g. biased locking). Authors of Java platform do like `synchronized` keyword and intrinsic-locking approach, they want programmers do not fear to use this handy tool (and prevent possible bugs). That's why `synchronized` optimizations and "synchronization is slow" myth busting was such a big deal for Sun and Oracle.

**"CPU-part" of the question:**
`synchronized` uses a locking mechanism that is built into the `JVM` and `MONITORENTER` / `MONITOREXIT` bytecode instructions. So the underlying implementation is JVM-specific (that is why it is called *intrinsic* lock) and AFAIK *usually* (subject to change) uses a pretty conservative strategy: once lock is "inflated" after threads collision on lock acquiring, `synchronized` begin to use OS-based locking ("fat locking") instead of fast CAS ("thin locking") and do not "like" to use CAS again soon (even if contention is gone).

`ReentrantLock` implementation is based on `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer` and coded in pure Java (uses CAS instructions and thread descheduling which was introduced it Java 5), so it is more stable across platforms,  offers more flexibility and tries to use fast CAS appoach for acquiring a lock *every time* (and OS-level locking if failed).

So, the main difference between these locks implementations in terms of performance is a lock acquiring strategy (which may not exist in specific JVM implementation or situation).

And there is no general answer which locking is better + **it is a subject to change during the time and platforms**. You should look at the specific problem and its nature to pick the most suitable solution (as usually in Java)

**PS:** you're pretty curious and I highly recommend you to look at HotSpot sources to go deeper (and to find out exact implementations for specific platform version). It may really help. Starting point is somewhere here: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/share/vm/runtime/synchronizer.cpp

Comment: but why Reentrant lock is/was 'faster' if the implementation is the same?

Comment: their semantics is the same for many scenarios, but not the implementation

Comment: Ok, but i'm courious: what's the difference in implementation? Why ReentrantLock is faster?

Comment: ahhh... now I've got your question! Yes, ReentrantLock uses CAS approach under the hood while acquiring the lock

Comment: out-of-topic question: are there other algorithms/methods for threads locking/synchronization except CAS?

Comment: I do believe that there are plenty of sophisticated locking algorithms in computer science (and most of them aren't used in production-ready platforms). But to my knowledge in Java we have only CAS (thin locking) and OS approaches (fat locking). PS: you are pretty curious :) I highly recommend you to look at HotSpot sources. For start: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/share/vm/runtime/synchronizer.cpp

Answer (score 1):

The ReentrantLock class, which implements Lock, has the same concurrency and memory semantics as synchronized, but also adds features like lock polling, timed lock waits, and interruptible lock waits. Additionally, it offers far better performance under heavy contention.

[Source](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp10264/)

Above answer is extract from [Brian Goetz's article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp10264/). You should read entire article. It helped me to understand differences in both.

Comment: The situation has evolved a lot since Java 5. In his book, Brian Goetz says that the performance of both varies from version to version, and that you shouldn't assume one is faster than the other, and you shouldn't make your choice based on performance concerns. Quote: *it  is  not  a  good  idea  to  choose  ReentrantLock  over  synchronized for performance reasons.*

Comment: @JBNizet as asked in question I wanted to tell both mechanism have same concurrency and memory semantics. Yes it is evolved but this statement still hold true.