# difference between lock/unlock vs wait/notify in the OS

Tags: java, reentrantlock

Title says it all, using a ReentrantLock, whats the difference between the lock unlock and using the condition with wait notify?

I know wait/notify is used with a condition, and inside a loop, is only that the difference?

How does the OS threats them differently?

Comment: There is no difference in the OS, because they aren't implemented in the OS.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36371149/reentrantlock-vs-synchronized-on-cpu-level) might help

Comment: @EJP well, my professor of distributed systems seems to disagree since he put that question on an exam :)

ok, but beeing primitives for the CPU what are the differecens between them?

Comment: @MadProgrammer will read it more thoughly but with a quick glance seems to not talk about the differences between lock and .wait.

Comment: It does, but it's comparing them at the class name instead of the method name

Comment: Olá caro estudante da universidade do minho :)

Comment: @marcospgp bom estudo :)