# Are java Lock implementations using synchronized code?

Tags: java, concurrency, locking, reentrantlock

It's said that `Lock` is better than `synchronized` because of many reasons like ability to use different scopes, fairness etc. But as far as I'm concerned, `synchronized` is something that's implemented with native code, while `ReentrantLock` and others seem to be usual java classes.

I've been looking through `ReentrantLock` source code in particular and can't seem to find any `synchronized` block. Could someone please explain how is it possible to synchronize different threads without using `synchronized` blocks? There seems to be a lot of operations, none of which are atomic.

UPD:
It's not exactly the same as the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36371149/reentrantlock-vs-synchronized-on-cpu-level) about CPU usage, it's rather than which exact tool is used in `Lock` implementations to provide synchronization. I made some more research and it turns out that in the heart of `ReentrantLock` there's a `native` method that acquires the `Lock`. So that would be the answer to my question.